# How do i remove a white border from a input button in html

Tags: html, css

```css
.KassTv{
    position: absolute;
    top: -213px;
    left: -382px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("Images/KassTv.png");
}

    .KassTv:hover{
    background-image: url("Images/LitTv.png");
}
```

```html
<form action="Home.htm">
    <input type="image" name="KassTv" class="KassTv" height="266" width="266" value="">
    </form>
```

This is my code. My button (which is an image) has a white border that I cant seem to remove. Any solutions are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add border: none; to the KassTv class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all borders then:

```css
.KassTv{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

It will remove all the borders and all the outlines if the button has.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but its not working. Im not sure if the image has a white border or its a border. I'm guessing now its the image. but at the same time if the image is removed it still has the border

Comment: @KhalilIbrahim okay so since in the code provided the button is the only element available inside the form, try using the same properties for your form as well. If it doesn't work still, then maybe the code provided is not correct, because there is no other problem in the code

Answer (score 0):

`.kassTv {border:none; outline: none }`

Add above CSS code to the .kassTv